# fast and slow moving products in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xampp

Can anyone help me out about fast and slow moving products on MySQL?

I want to know how to `SELECT CLAUSE` all the fast moving products and the slow moving products seperately. Here are my tables.

```
**product**
productID
productname
price

**sales**
transactionID
productID
quantity
subtotal

**transaction**
transactionID
datetransact
```

I cut some of the columns to make it look simple.

`FAST MOVING PRODUCTS` is a product that have been sold often in a specific period of time.
`SLOW MOVING PRODUCTS` is a product that sell not so often and sit on the shelves on a long period of time.

Comment: What defines a "fast moving product" and a "slow moving product"?

Comment: i edit my post to explain it, hope you understand.

Comment: So you want to select products based on a frequency of transactions within a specific datetransact range?

Comment: rank them according to frequency sold in a datetransact range. yes sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scott's answer is good as far as it goes.  First, you seem to be concerned about the quantity of the products sold not just the number of transactions containing the product.  And, the question (which has perhaps been revised) is about a particular date range.

To get the answer for a particular range of dates, simply use a `where` clause or conditional aggregation.  The following uses filtering *and* includes products with no sales:

```
select p.*, sum(s.quantity) as productssold,
       sum(s.quantity) / datediff(@datelast, @datefirst)) as AvgPerDay
from product p left join
     sales s
     on p.productid = s.productid left join
     transaction t
     on s.transactionid = t.transactionid
where t.datetransact between @datefirst and @datelast
group by p.productid
order by AvgPerDay;
```

If you don't want products that never sold, simple change the `left join` back to inner joins.

The problem with the filtering approach is that some products may have had their first sale *after* beginning of your period.  To handle this, you want to measure the average since the first sales date (or perhaps since some release date in the `product` table).  This basically moves the date condition from the `where` clause to the `having` clause:

```
select p.*, sum(case when t.datetransact between @datefirst and @datelast then s.quantity else 0 end
               ) as productssold,
       (sum(case when t.datetransact between @datefirst and @datelast then s.quantity else 0 end) /
        datediff(@datelast, least(@datefirst, max(t.datetransact)))
       ) as AvgPerDay
from product p left join
     sales s
     on p.productid = s.productid left join
     transaction t
     on s.transactionid = t.transactionid
group by p.productid
order by AvgPerDay;
```

Comment: Wow, thanks man, the first block of code can be useful as deadstock. products that can't be sold from the datefirst and datelast. you guys aer so helpful, this can be a useful reference to others too. thanks alot!

Comment: wait theres a problem here. my sales table had sold 5 product, if i ran the clause above. it return a null value on avgperday and item sold returned 0.

Comment: @MharveenBiu . . . Did you define the variables `@datefirst` and `@datelast`?  If this persists, can you set up an example on SQL Fiddle.

Comment: i don't know what you're talking about define variable in mysql query. im not an advance user yet. but it would be nice if you teach me. am i going to run sql including @datefirst and @datelast?

Comment: Plug in your dates for `@datefirst` and `@datelast`.

Comment: thanks to both of you sir. credits to you guys! both are correct is just that @gordon code can declare '@datefirst' and '@datelast' and can see deadstock products.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to group by product and select the min(datetransact) and max(datetransact).  The difference of these two will give you the number of products sold and the timespan between the first and last sale date.  Then you can divide these to get an average.

**Updated to calculate on quantity sold.**

```
select sum(sales.quantity) as productssold,
       min(transaction.datetransact) as firstsale,
       max(transaction.datetransact) as lastsale,
       max(transaction.datetransact) - min(transaction.datetransact) as timespan,
       sum(sales.quantity) / max(transaction.datetransact) - min(transaction.datetransact) as averagesold
from product
join sales on product.productid = sales.productid
join transaction on sales.transactionid = transaction.transactionid
group by product.productid
having averagesold >= 'desired value'
```

Comment: Wow! just what i need, it counts how many products sold in a specific time range it just need to be asc and desc like fast and slow.thank you sir!

Comment: oh wait, how can i put a desired value on the first sale and last sale? for example. i want select the top products sold to 8/24/2014 which is today from 7/24/2014 which is last month?

Comment: sir, there is a problem in the productsold, it only count the product appear in the sales table, not the actual quantity that the product sold. -_-